# How to write a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

**Quality**

```
id    name
----------
 1    bold
 2    Frank
 3    Quite
 4    friendly
```

**Student**

```
id name
---------
 1  A
 2  B
 3  C
```

**StudentQuality**

```
id  fk_qual  fk_stud
 1   1        1
 2   2        1
 3   1        2
 4   2        2
 5   3        2
 6   1        3
 7   2        3
 8   3        3
 9   4        3
```

These are my tables. How do I get the students who are bold, frank and quite.
If I use `IN` operation, I get all the 3 students, I need to get only 2 students
If I use bold, frank, I should get all the 3 students
If I use bold, frank, quite and friendly, I should get all the 1 students
So how to query this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text, please. When you edit, mark the code and click `{}`.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like:

1. Declaring a table variable, holding the values you're searching for
2. Selecting the data and using your table variable as a condition for the INNER JOIN and counting the values of the table variable and compare them to the amount of qualities

Like:

```
DECLARE  @qualities table(qname  varchar(100));
INSERT INTO   @qualities   
       VALUES ('bold'),('Frank'),('Quite');

       SELECT S.name
         FROM Student S
   INNER JOIN StudentQuality SQ
           ON S.id = SQ.fk_stud
   INNER JOIN Quality Q
           ON SQ.fk_qual = Q.id
          AND Q.name in (SELECT qname FROM @qualities)          
      GROUP BY S.name
      HAVING count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(qname) FROM @qualities)
```

Comment: Nice solution. I guess table variable is not really necessary, is it?

Comment: well, not 100% necessary. thats just one idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT fk_stud 
  FROM StudentQuality sq
  JOIN Quality q ON sq.fk_qual = q.id
  WHERE q.name IN ('bold')
)
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT fk_stud 
  FROM StudentQuality sq
  JOIN Quality q ON sq.fk_qual = q.id
  WHERE q.name IN ('frank')
)
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT fk_stud 
  FROM StudentQuality sq
  JOIN Quality q ON sq.fk_qual = q.id
  WHERE q.name IN ('quite')
)
```

or without `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT fk_stud 
  FROM StudentQuality sq
  JOIN Quality q ON sq.fk_qual = q.id
  WHERE q.name IN ('bold')
) and id IN
(
  SELECT fk_stud 
  FROM StudentQuality sq
  JOIN Quality q ON sq.fk_qual = q.id
  WHERE q.name IN ('frank')
) and id IN
(
  SELECT fk_stud 
  FROM StudentQuality sq
  JOIN Quality q ON sq.fk_qual = q.id
  WHERE q.name IN ('quite')
)
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the best option

Answer (score 0):

Another variation

```
SELECT s.id,min(s.name) studentname FROM student s
INNER JOIN (studentquality sq INNER JOIN quality q ON q.id=sq.fk_qual)
ON sq.fk_stud=s.id WHERE q.name in ('bold','frank','quite') group by s.id
having length(group_concat(q.name))=length(concat('bold,','frank,','quite'));

SELECT s.id,min(s.name) studentname, (group_concat(q.name)) qname FROM student s
INNER JOIN (studentquality sq INNER JOIN quality q ON q.id=sq.fk_qual)
ON sq.fk_stud=s.id WHERE q.name in ('bold','frank','quite') group by s.id
having length(qname)=length(concat('bold,','frank,','quite'));
```